# How to describe behavior of population system, given by system of ODEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, systems-of-equations

So I have a system of equations:$$x'(t)=x(t)(4-2x(t)-y(t))\\y'(t)=y(t)(3-x(t)-y(t)) $$

What I understand so far is: if we have x being the population of prey and y is the population of predators. x grows at a rate proportional to x, but decays at a rate proportional to the interaction (xy). y increases at a rate proportional to xy and decreases at a rate due to the size of y (more predators = less food, etc.).

Given that there are no initial values, how can I describe this population system governed by the above equations?

Comment: There are two initial conditions $y(0)$ and $x(0)$. If you want to study it numerically then just pick different vaues and study the resulting solution. However you can study the dynamical system analytically also by looking for fixpoints ($\{x'(t),y'(t)\} = \{0,0\}$) and [analyzing them](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotka%E2%80%93Volterra_equation#Dynamics_of_the_system).

Comment: Given $t=0$, how are you supposed to determine the solution without an accompanying y value? I understand that looking at fixed points  is important, however, how would this help in determining the functions meaning?

Comment: I am afraid you might have missed that the (excellent) answer you accepted mentions (rather briefly) that there exists a systematic approach to answer this kind of question, not based on visualization tools (that are also quite useful) but on actual mathematics. Are you aware of this fact? I am asking you this because of your comment mentioning "the convergence of $f_1(x,y)$", quite offtopic, which seems to indicate otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the functions
$$
\begin{cases}
f_1(x,y)=x(4-2x-y)\\
f_2(x,y)=y(3-x-y)
\end{cases}
$$
and study them (fixpoints (common zeros) and signs studies and so on). I leave also a plot of the vector field $(x,y)\mapsto (f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y))$. From it, you can see how different solutions will evolve in time. The point $(x,y)=(1,2)$ is marked in red, why?

[image: vector field plot of the system]

Comment: Thank you for replying! Is the red dot due to the convergence of $f_1(x.,y)$ and $f_2(x.y)$? If this is true, then an initial value would $f(1)=2$, correct?

Comment: @anon This plot shows that whatever (poitive) initial conditions you choose the system will eventually reach the fixpoint (pick a point and follow the arrows). The fixpoint is a so-called [attractor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attractor). Nice answer btw.